# Trying to compile a simple Ada program, getting GNAT compiling error in OS 14.1 (23B73) on a M2 MBP

Tags: macos, ada

```
❯ alr build
ⓘ Building myproj/myproj.gpr...
Link
   [link]         myproj.adb
0  0x10034af43  __assert_rtn + 64
1  0x10024cf43  ld::AtomPlacement::findAtom(unsigned char, unsigned long long, ld::AtomPlacement::AtomLoc const*&, long long&) const + 1411
2  0x100269431  ld::InputFiles::SliceParser::parseObjectFile(mach_o::Header const*) const + 19745
3  0x100279e44  ld::InputFiles::parseAllFiles(void (ld::AtomFile const*) block_pointer)::$_7::operator()(unsigned long, ld::FileInfo const&) const + 1380
4  0x7ff8051315cd  _dispatch_client_callout2 + 8
5  0x7ff805141e3e  _dispatch_apply_invoke + 214
6  0x7ff80513159a  _dispatch_client_callout + 8
7  0x7ff80514099d  _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 879
8  0x7ff805140f22  _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 152
9  0x7ff8052d5c06  _pthread_wqthread + 262
ld: Assertion failed: (resultIndex < sectData.atoms.size()), function findAtom, file Relocations.cpp, line 1336.
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gprbuild: link of myproj.adb failed
gprbuild: failed command was: /users/sdey02/.config/alire/cache/dependencies/gnat_native_13.2.1_c21501ad/bin/gcc myproj.o b__myproj.o -L/Users/sdey02/myproj/obj/development/ -L/Users/sdey02/myproj/obj/development/ -L/users/sdey02/.config/alire/cache/dependencies/gnat_native_13.2.1_c21501ad/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0/13.2.0/adalib/ /users/sdey02/.config/alire/cache/dependencies/gnat_native_13.2.1_c21501ad/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0/13.2.0/adalib/libgnat.a -Wl,-rpath,@executable_path/..//obj/development -Wl,-rpath,@executable_path/../..//.config/alire/cache/dependencies/gnat_native_13.2.1_c21501ad/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0/13.2.0/adalib -o /Users/sdey02/myproj/bin//myproj
error: Command ["gprbuild", "-s", "-j0", "-p", "-P", "/Users/sdey02/myproj/myproj.gpr"] exited with code 4
error: Compilation failed.
```

Error seems to be this:
`ld: Assertion failed: (resultIndex < sectData.atoms.size()), function findAtom, file Relocations.cpp, line 1336.`

I ran the alr build command and expected the crate to build but instead got an exited with code 4 error.

I checked other threads and it seems to be an issue with the latest version of cmd line tools. What are my options to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `-Wl,-ld_classic` to linker switches:

```
alr build -- -largs -Wl,-ld_classic
```

More details:

- https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.ada/c/gNXI3bS3iaw
- https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.ada/c/8LwmJRwEdWs